# Set environment variable when Jboss starts

Tags: java, unix, jboss, environment-variables, jboss7.x

I am trying to set the environment variable in **Jboss** file (`/etc/profile.d/jboss.sh`) for one of the software I am using in my application.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_45/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_45/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_45/../lib/amd64::/opt/ABBYY/FREngine11/Bin
export PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PATH
```

But when I restart the jboss using below commands

```
sudo service jboss stop  
sudo service jboss start
```

and check if the env variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has been set, I get a empty value.

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>>
```

and echo'ing `PATH` also does not show that path.

```
echo $PATH
>> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: have you checked that /etc/profile.d/jboss.sh is actually being invoked by your service command?